# Laravel 5.2 all routes work EXCEPT the home route

Tags: apache, .htaccess, routes, laravel-5

I have a project that I am moving from my development server to my hosting server. I have set the Document route in the Apache config to the public folder. The strange behavior I am getting is that all routes work EXCEPT the home route... or the '/' route. This all works on my development server but I never set the document root to the public folder. So aside from that, I expected it to work. It's very strange. www.example.com loads a blank page, no error. However, www.example.com/events works fine, or any sub-route for that matter. I git pushed the entire project up to the production server (if that sparks any ideas). For now, I have included my current .htaccess file below. I have tried many things with the .htaccess as I am assuming this is the problem but with no luck! Looking forward to any suggestions!

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index.php [L]
```

I have made all permissions on files to 644 and folders to 755. Then I set permissions on the storage and public folders to 777 after that just to ensure they had the access they needed - I can restrict them once I figure out my problem(s). This is the first Laravel based project I've ever moved to production so please don't take anything for granted and throw your ideas at me! :) Finally, I am getting nothing in the error logs when I try to access the main page at all. They remain empty.

UPDATE: When I do this to my routes file I do not get any text, still just the WSD (White Screen of Death):

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! Hopefully this will help others...

I had to comment out one of the first lines in the index.php found in the public folder. This is the line you are looking for:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) return false;
```

If you think about it for a minute it makes sense, but was so frustrating. Once you comment out that line you should be good to go! This bug was created by using an add-on package (that works with a chrome extension) to allow you to see all your raw SQL queries generated by the Laravel Query Builder. had I not have been using this package I wouldn't have had an issue. Hope this is helpful to someone else! Enjoy!